# Bootstrap: Center link on div with a inline list

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I center a link in a div that also has an inline list on Bootstrap? The star link seems not to be centered even if I use `.text-center` class.

```
<div class="project-status text-center">
    <a class="favourites" href=""><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></a>

    <ul class="mylist list-unstyled list-inline pull-right">
        <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ga6p8dcx/1/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this http://jsfiddle.net/ga6p8dcx/2/

```
.project-status {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.mylist {
    margin: 0;
}

.favourites {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will center if you set display to inline-block and width 100%, but this causes the links to drop to the next line, the star was not centered as the center text did not take these links into account